# How to run shell command in JIRA script runner groovy

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to configure Jenkins build trigger from Jira post-function Groovy script

Here is my Groovy code:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.util.UserMessageUtil

def WANITOPUSHField =  ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(10802);//customfield id
def WANITOPUSHValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(WANITOPUSHField);
def SelectVersionField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(10805);//customfield id
def SelectVersionValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(SelectVersionField);

if(WANITOPUSHField != null) {
    if(WANITOPUSHValue.toString() == 'Yes') {
       'curl --user USERNAME:PASSWORD  "http://JENKINS_URL/job/deploy-dev-test/buildWithParameters?token=MYTOCKEN&ENV=1"'.execute()
       UserMessageUtil.success("Jenkins Build started ");

    } else {
        UserMessageUtil.success("Condition Not sucsess "+WANITOPUSHValue.toString());
    }
}
```

Here I have used curl command to trigger Jenkins build if the Jira ticket status changed, but the curl command is not working here

It is throwing output on the alert box

```
java.lang.UNIXProcess@4d0c79da
```

I don't know what its mean whether the command is executing successfully or not, Please anyone can help me on this and suggest me if I can use some different method with Groovy to achieve this

Comment: Passwords in Unix program arguments are public for all processes. See: `ls -ef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"something".execute() returns instance of UNIXProcess java class. When toString() method is not overriden you will see something like java.lang.UNIXProcess@4d0c79da

Here some code which will help you to get shell command output:

```
def command = 'curl --user USERNAME:PASSWORD  "http://JENKINS_URL/job/deploy-dev-test/buildWithParameters?token=MYTOCKEN&ENV=1"'
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

println "Process exit code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
println "Std Err: ${proc.err.text}"
println "Std Out: ${proc.in.text}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, `def command = 'curl --user USERNAME:PASSWORD  http://JENKINS_URL/job/deploy-dev-test/buildWithParameters?token=MYTOCKEN&ENV=1'` This works for me

Comment: Works great! I had to remove the quotes around the URL though.